# How can I eliminate the segfaults that occur in working code only when debugging with ipdb?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, ipdb

I am using:

- Python: 3.11.0
- Django: 4.2.8
- djangorestframework 3.14.0
- sqlite: 3.38.5

When I'm debugging and I use 'n' to go over a method, I sometimes get a segfault where there is no problem running the code normally. I can move my 'ipdb.set_trace()' to immediately after the call that caused the segfault, rerun the test and continue debugging but this is tedious.

One cause I've tracked, is under the django reverse function. Here, the `<URLResolver <module 'rest_framework.urls' from '/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosmgrweb/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/urls.py'> (rest_framework:rest_framework) 'api-auth/'>` causes the segfault when its _populate method is invoked.

I *could* start upgrading everything but this is a large application with many dependencies and I'd like to be confident that this problem will be eliminated if I go down that road.

Does anyone know what the cause of this is and how I can resolve it?

Comment: How close are you to memory constraints? If your test suite uses 80% of RAM, you may just hit the limits. Is it really a segfault or some other irrecoverable hard error? Also, 3.11.0 may really be your problem: first release is always buggy, can you afford upgrading to newer patch version? At least in dev environment this shouldn't require any other changes, likely faster than debugging such an issue.

Comment: I can update the patch version without a problem and upgrading python to 3.12 is doable. I'll give that a go shortly and report back.
It is a segfault and memory resources are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.11.0 was causing this problem. Upgrading the venv to use python 3.11.8 has got rid of it and I can now use ipdb without it segfaulting (as tested so far).

Comment: There were several fixes in between: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99729, https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100942, https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106092, https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/102397, ... If you want to know the specific cause, you can try bisecting python patch version first, and then look through [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/changelog.html) of the first non-failing version.